# Run command after opening terminal window from script using bash

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, terminal, xcode

I have a very simple script I use to open Terminal from Xcode in project root folder:

```
#!/bin/bash
open -a Terminal "`pwd`"
```

I want to extend it to run `pod install` command so I've added && to run it.

```
#!/bin/bash
open -a Terminal "`pwd`" && pod install
```

It won't run the second command. I've tried with single &, putting pod install into another script and calling but didn't manage do execute. How would I do this ? 
I'm thinking since Xcode runs the script to open the terminal, the terminal has no idea about the pod install, so maybe if there is a way to pass input parameter to terminal that would need to be ran.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Opening a new terminal from the command line and running a command on Mac OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/174576/opening-a-new-terminal-from-the-command-line-and-running-a-command-on-mac-os-x)

Comment: @Darko : I don't understand from your question what exactly is the desired effect. From the man page of `open`, I conclude that the arguments which come afterwards, are passed to the application (_Terminal_). In your case, this just the string ``pwd``  (Terminal would not see the `&&...` part, because this is already consumed by the shell.

Answer (score 0):

( Ive not tried this, just gleened it from the man page)

I expect the problem is the launcher is running the terminal command, and then running the pod command, rather then running the pod command afterwards. I think what you want to do is run the pod command IN the terminal.

Try

```
#!/bin/bash
open -a Terminal "`pwd`" -e "pod install"
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the backquotes don't make sense. They have the effect of running the working directory as a **command**.

Then, the && is a statement separator. You basically executed a

```
open -a Terminal "`pwd`" 
pod install
```

with the only difference that `pod` in your case is only executed, if `open` returns exit code zero. This means that the `pod` command is not executed inside the terminal.

Now my assumption is that you want to run `pod install` in a new terminal window. You can pass to `open -a Terminal` the path to one executable, so

```
open -a Terminal "pod install"
```

would not work, because there is not executable of the name `pod install`. Instead you would create somewhere (say in your `~/bin`) a script which performs this task. I.e.

You have an executable script `~/pod_inst`, which contains i.e.

```
#!/bin/zsh
pod install
```

and run it as

```
open -a Terminal ~/bin/pod_inst
```

Things get trickier if the script requires dynamic arguments. Say that you want to run the script in the working directory from which you do the `open` call (by default, the new terminal would run it in your home directory). Unfortunately, passing this information via the environment does not work (because `open` acts as if you had clicked on the Terminal app on your desktop, which means that you get a fresh environment).

For passing variables, you could make your pod_inst to accept a configuration file of a name you have agreed upon. The script now becomes:

```
#!/bin/zsh
conf_file=~/.pod_inst
[[ -f $conf_file ]] && source $conf_file
if [[ -n $wd ]] && cd $wd
pod install
```

To have `pod install` being executed in your current working directory, you now do a

```
echo wd="$PWD" >~/.pod_inst # Create the configuration ...
open -a Terminal ~/bin/pod_inst # Run the script in new terminal
```